# Time Series Forecasting Technique, I have a Date Column which has data like this: 08JUL13:05:06:00

Tags: sas

I want to forecast for next year, i have data for 2013. dates are in format:

08JUL13:05:06:00

for data preparation it takes intervals as minutes and whenever i change interval there is no output.

Also when Interval is in minutes my data has lot of missing values which i understand because this is billing data for entire year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `datepart()` function. it takes only date from date-time format

so `datepart('08JUL13:05:06:00'dt)` returns `'08Jul13'd`

```
data want;
data have
date_Column = Datepart(Date)
format date_Column date9.;
run;
```

Comment: i tired creating a new column  MONTH = month(DATEPART(date)); as i want time intervals to be in months, also this column is numeric in type and whenever i take it as time ID the output has no data, it give empty table.

Comment: SAS uses numeric values as date, so if you want to use it as TIME_ID you have to use `FORMAT=AFRDFDD8.`

Comment: also, `month()` returns only NUMBER of month, in your case, June would become '6'.

if you want to have month, i would suggest using `intnx('month', datepart(date), 0)` - this will return '01Jun2013'. Just don't forget the `FORMAT=AFRDFDD8.`